# Best approache structure for a large database table

Tags: database, postgresql, e-commerce

Let say i have a application where users can upload a file with products. The particularity is users can upload same products but with some something diferent like quantity, describe, price, or supplier even category, that make me to say a user can have many products but a product can have only one user. The problem is ..if i have like 1000 users and every user upload a list with 100.000 products, my table products will be very very big, so i think will be some problems about performances. In first time i think about make a products table per user like table_products_user_id but i dont think is the good way, so i need help. Please suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If different users are associated with the same product, you don't have to store each product multiple times.

If the products are all different, the design is simple: two tables with a foreign key relationship.

1000 times 100000 is 100000000, which is big, but no problem with PostgreSQL.

If you make sure that all access to the big table is via indexes, the queries will be fast.

If you need sequential scans, but you know that e.g. you always query products for a certain user, partitioning the big table by user will help.

One important consideration is how you want to get rid of old data. Partitioning the table can make that convenient.